# Can asyncio.DatagramTransport.sendto be starved with CPU computation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm sending data through multiple transports

```
for transport in transports:
                transport.sendto(packet)
```

The list of transports is created like:

```
for country, ip in countries:
    if country != my_country:
        t, _ = await self._loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
            lambda: ClientProtocol(country), remote_addr=(ip, port)
        )
        transports.add(t)  # type: ignore
```

Sendto is defined as:

```
def sendto(self, data, addr=None):
        """Send data to the transport.

        This does not block; it buffers the data and arranges for it
        to be sent out asynchronously.
        addr is target socket address.
        If addr is None use target address pointed on transport creation.
        """
```

What is confusing me is that `sendto` is said not to block, but it is not labelled as an `async` function. If there are no awaits in my main loop and I am doing a lot of CPU computation, will the `sendto` be starved? Will I need to add in some `await`s in order to ensure that the data will always be sent?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using this API at all. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html), "Transports and Protocols are used by the **low-level** event loop APIs... Essentially, transports and protocols should only be used in libraries and frameworks and **never in high-level asyncio applications**."

Comment: Unfortunately, this particular application is very latency sensitive and am interested in using the most efficient APIs available.

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio.DatagramTransport.sendto` can be starved by CPU computation. The docs don't explain this, but if we look at [one of the Python 3.9.0 implementations](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L1031) of this method:

```
def sendto(self, data, addr=None):
    if not isinstance(data, (bytes, bytearray, memoryview)):
        raise TypeError(f'data argument must be a bytes-like object, '
                        f'not {type(data).__name__!r}')
    if not data:
        return

    if self._address:
        if addr not in (None, self._address):
            raise ValueError(
                f'Invalid address: must be None or {self._address}')
        addr = self._address

    if self._conn_lost and self._address:
        if self._conn_lost >= constants.LOG_THRESHOLD_FOR_CONNLOST_WRITES:
            logger.warning('socket.send() raised exception.')
        self._conn_lost += 1
        return

    if not self._buffer:
        # Attempt to send it right away first.
        try:
            if self._extra['peername']:
                self._sock.send(data)
            else:
                self._sock.sendto(data, addr)
            return
        except (BlockingIOError, InterruptedError):
            self._loop._add_writer(self._sock_fd, self._sendto_ready)
        except OSError as exc:
            self._protocol.error_received(exc)
            return
        except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
            raise
        except BaseException as exc:
            self._fatal_error(
                exc, 'Fatal write error on datagram transport')
            return

    # Ensure that what we buffer is immutable.
    self._buffer.append((bytes(data), addr))
    self._maybe_pause_protocol()
```

we see that if the underlying socket operation would block, the method uses `self._loop._add_writer` to tell the event loop to call `self._sendto_ready` when the socket is ready. If you don't return control to the event loop, the event loop will never get a chance to call `_sendto_ready`, and the data will not be sent.